# Variable variable in grails like in php

Tags: variables, grails

I am trying to achieve **variable variable** concept of PHP in grails, my code structure is somewhat similar to,

```
<%
    def a = 6
    def b = "a"
    println "${"$b"}"
%>
```

I would like the output of

```
println "${"$b"}"
```

6, is it possible in any way?

Comment: the data is passed from the controller in some structure like `[template:"something.gsp",model:["age":5,"date":"2011-01-01","id":9, listedKey:["age","date","id"]]]` now when I iterate over the list listedKey I would like to get the value of its respective variable in view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the data is passed from the controller in some structure like [template:"something.gsp",model:["age":5,"date":"2011-01-01","id":9, listedKey:["age","date","id"]]] now when I iterate over the list listedKey I would like to get the value of its respective variable in view

Access the model map like this:

```
<g:each in=${listedKey} var="key">
   ${binding[key]}
</g:each>
```

Comment: Both the variable and value has been preassigned in another service and separately so I must use predefined assignment and cannot create new variable in view so this doesn't quite help.

Comment: So why don't you just use `<% out << $a %>`? Can you be a bit more precise what you actually are trying to achieve?

Comment: the data is passed from the controller in some structure like `[template:"something.gsp",model:["age":5,"date":"2011-01-01","id":9, listedKey:["age","date","id"]]]` now when I iterate over the list listedKey I would like to get the value of its respective variable in view

Comment: okay. that is more precise :) I've edited my answer. take a look please

Comment: I don't think model can be accessed in such a way in view, populating the values in form of different map had crossed my mind but the data set is too large and will require change in lots of previous legacy codes, so map is not currently an option for me.

Comment: Not sure if it's called model or just bindings[key] or binding[key] . But each view has the model bound to it

Comment: looks like it's `binding`, although this method seems a little resource heavy, guess I have to work with it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following just straight in the gsp:

```
<g:set var="a" value="${6}"/>
<g:set var="b" value="a"/>

${a} 
"${b}"
```

or

```
<%
    def a = 6
    def b = "a"
    out << b
%>
${b} <- also working
```